# Kosala in the Vedas

Tags: vedas, rama

Is the **Kosala empire** to which Lord Rāma Belonged mentioned anywhere in the Vedic Texts?

pls provide me with 4-5 refrences from Vedic texts **(Be it Brāhmaṇas , Āraṇyakas or Upaniṣads)** that mention **Kosala** or **Kausalya Rulers.**

Thanks

[image]